# Advanced Calculus by Callahan vs Functions of Several Variables by Fleming

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I have a knowledge of Calculus, Differential Equations, and Linear Algebra, I want to learn advanced calculus, but I'm wondering what book is the best choice, I want to learn it rigorously "enough" but not to the point where someone would call me a mathematician i.e. Calculus by Lang vs Calculus by Spivak, certainly Lang is rigorous but Spivak is at a higher level, though Lang is enough for a physicist.

I also want to learn it in differential forms approach after, i.e, Advanced Calculus: A Differential Forms Approach by Edwards. I have to choices,

Advanced Calculus by Callahan - longer but has more geometric arguments and diagrams Functions of Several Variables by Fleming - shorter but harder? I think Fleming has an advantage because it is shorter, but Callahan is newer and might have some topics that are not in Fleming's book, it also has more explanations and diagrams.

Which do you think suits me best? Do you think if I read Fleming instead of Callahan I'll miss some important discussions in Callahan? As of now I'm more into Fleming since it's shorter. I don't have much time to read two books fully, so I just need to choose one and concentrate on that.

Comment: If you want to learn the differential forms approach, why not just read Edwards' book?  I've read the first couple of chapters and they weren't that advanced.  Have you already taken a course in multivariable calculus?

Comment: @BobbieD Yes I have taken Multicalc, so you think I can go straight with Edwards? What do you think with those two other books?

Comment: I haven't read the other two, but as long as you're solid on partial derivatives and have seen multiple integrals before I don't think Edwards is going to be out of reach.  In fact he doesn't even assume knowledge of linear algebra.

Comment: @BobbieD Ok, thanks for your advice!